# На какую максимальную степень тройки может делиться x^2+y^2?

Tags: математика

Пусть x,y – натуральные числа. Известно, что произведение xy=14467005. На какую максимальную степень тройки может делиться x^2+y^2?

Answer (score 3):

## 10

```
1215*1215 + 11907*11907 = 143252874 = 2426*3^10

1701*1701 + 8505*8505   =  75228426 = 1274*3^10
```

Ладно, давайте математически...

14467005 = 3^10 *5 *7^2

Значит, раскладывая на составляющие, можно получить 3^10, если дать по 3^5 в x и в y (x = 3^5*a, y = 3^5*b).

x*x+y*y = 3^10*(a*a+b*b), где a*b = 5*7*7.

Просто ручками перебрать разложения 5*7*7 - тут всего несколько вариантов (1 и 5*7*7, 5 и 7*7, 7 и 5*7) - и убедиться, что ни один из них не дает лишнюю тройку...

Ну, а 10 строк исчерпывающего перебора подтверждают написанное :)

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как Вы пришли к этому ответу?

Comment: Это сайт программистов - пришел к нему при помощи 10 строк кода :)

Comment: Перебором, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: А еще 243*243+59535*59535=3544475274=3^10*60026

Comment: @Mikhailo Да, ваш вариант соответствует 1 + 5*7*7.

Comment: вы можете точно ответить на поставленный вопрос.На какую максимальную степень.

Comment: По-моему, я уже ответил. В самой первой точке своего ответа - там ясно написано число 10. Сейчас увеличу его, раз вы не видите... Так лучше?